# XSLT : How to get the value of the parent tag based on the condition which is dependent on the values of its child tags, in a highly nested XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to get the solution for this, but still cannot find a proper solution.
I referred few links [Nested for-each loops, accessing outer element with variable from the inner loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436237/nested-for-each-loops-accessing-outer-element-with-variable-from-the-inner-loop) and [How to extract child tags text and extended text of parent tag from xml using xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413801/how-to-extract-child-tags-text-and-extended-text-of-parent-tag-from-xml-using-xs) but these questions don't have the nested tags.

My XML:

```
<catalog title="TitleABC1">
  <cd>
    <title code="Y">Picture book</title>
    <artist>Simply Red</artist>
    <country>EU</country>
  </cd>
  <catalog title="TitleABC2">
    <cd>
      <cd>
        <title code="N">Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
      </cd>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <cd>
        <cd>
          <title code="Y">Hide your heart</title>
          <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
          <country>UK</country>
        </cd>
      </cd>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <catalog title="TitleABC3">
        <cd>
          <title code="N">Red</title>
          <artist>The Communards</artist>
          <country>UK</country>
        </cd>
      </catalog>
    </cd>
    <cd>
      <title code="N">Unchain my heart</title>
      <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
      <country>USA</country>
    </cd>
  </catalog>
</catalog>
```

For above XML, the condition is that titles of only those `catalog` tags will be displayed if any of the child/descendants `title` tags have the code attribute as 'Y'.

Hence, the Output should be like:

```
TitleABC1
TitleABC2
```

I was trying at the below logic for XSLT, but couldn't get the desired solution.

```
 <xsl:template match="catalog">
<!-- Store the value in a variable -->
              <xsl:for-each select="//title">
<!-- <xsl:if> to check for the code attrib -->                                                 
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Since you started the question by explaining how you attempted to find an answer, let me comment on your problem-solving strategy. Searching the web for existing code that matches your English-language description of the problem is unlikely to work: it's a bit like searching for "add 3 to 17", which will fail to find code that successfully adds 4 to 18. It would be much better to invest effort in understanding the basic operations of the language, such as path expressions, axes, and filter expressions, and learning how to combine them yourself.

Comment: Yes @MichaelKay, you are right. I'm not aware of the path expressions, axes. Certainly, I would look more into these topics and study them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only those `catalog` tags will be displayed if any of the
>   child/descendants `title` tags have the code attribute as 'Y'.

Why don't you do exactly what you said needs to be done:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//catalog[descendant::title/@code='Y']">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Or, if you prefer a recursive approach:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="catalog[descendant::title/@code='Y']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You need to know about the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) in order to understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. It took me sometime to understand the solution and it correctly serves the purpose. Thanks again.